# how to change commnd field select to view in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to change the command field name from "select" to "view details". How to change the command field text name. I want to make column to display details on record. how to rename the column header and data text field of command field

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GvLeads" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="LeadId" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Company" DataField="Companyname" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Contact Person" DataField="ContactPerson" />
      <asp:CommandField HeaderText="View" ShowSelectButton="true"  />
   </Coloumns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SelectText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.selecttext(v=vs.110).aspx) property like this:-

```
<asp:CommandField HeaderText="View" ShowSelectButton="true" selecttext="view details"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use then SelectText Property!

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GvLeads" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
      <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="LeadId" />
               <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Company" DataField="Companyname" />                 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Contact Person" DataField="ContactPerson" />
               <asp:CommandField SelectText="View Details" HeaderText="View" ShowSelectButton="true" />
     </Coloumns>
 </asp:GridView>
```